# add custom class to image gallery in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

I'm new to wordpress and am using a custom theme (http://demo.richwp.com/showcasedark/).

I want to use my own custom lightbox script (which requires a custom class for each image), but I am stuck trying to apply that class to my image galleries.

For example, every image defaults to this html code:

> a href="_images/anim_reel001.jpg" (followed by img source details)

I want it to look like this:

> a href="_images/anim_reel001.jpg" class="view" (followed by img source details)

It seems like the way to do this is by creating a custom function in my functions.php file, but I'm totally clueless to PHP scripting.  Also, I'm unsure if this will work with existing images or only works with new images/galleries I upload.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a plugin for WP that can do this for you? I would not recommend touching the WP core. Even if you did know what you were doing.

Comment: Hello @user2648150 is jQuery an option for you? Because it's very easy to do that way and you would be sure that it works with all galleries.

Comment: Also, if `functions.php` sounds better for you then I think this post will help. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65982/customize-the-wordpress-default-gallery-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If jQuery is an option... you can target all galleries and make sure to add that class to the anchors. You can see this in action here:

### [The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/5FhqC/)

View the source on the placeholder images in the fiddle result and you can see that even though in the markup the `<a>` had no class it now does.

This works with 3 blocks of code to mimic what the WordPress gallery outputs.

### HTML

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery">
  <dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="75" height="75" src="http://dummyimage.com/75x75/000/fff.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
      </a>
    </dt>
  </dl>

  <dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="75" height="75" src="http://dummyimage.com/75x75/000/fff.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
      </a>
    </dt>
  </dl>

  <dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="75" height="75" src="http://dummyimage.com/75x75/000/fff.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
      </a>
    </dt>
  </dl>

  <dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="75" height="75" src="http://dummyimage.com/75x75/000/fff.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
      </a>
    </dt>
  </dl>
```

### CSS

```
#gallery-1 {
  margin: auto;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-item {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;            }
#gallery-1 img {
  border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.gallery').each(function(i) {
    $('.attachment-thumbnail').parent().addClass('view');
  });
});
```

The good stuff is happening in the jQuery block of code because you can see that when the document is ready we are going through all the galleries by selecting them with `div.gallery` and then we are looping through each of them to find the `.attachment-thumbnail` class which is given to the `<img>` thumb for the WordPress gallery and we are targeting the `<img>`'s parent which happens to be the `<a>` tag and adding that class you wanted called `.view`.

It's worth to note that to make this solution work for you, you need to have jQuery included in your file, otherwise this will just not work. Chances are that you already have jQuery included.

Comment: Your code works perfectly in isolation, using the demo link above.  For some reason, when I implement it in the head of my header.php, it only applies the class to `<img>` tag and not the `<a href>`.  I've confirmed that jquery and javascript are working.

Comment: that is strange... but to debug it I'd need to see your actual code to see why the selector is not working right. We might be able to make it more specific like: `$('.attachment-thumbnail').parents('a').addClass('view');` this used the `.parents()` method instead to `.parent()`... this is in case your gallery structure is different in the markup... we are being more specific looking for the `<a>`

Comment: Damn, still doesn't work, but I feel like I'm so close! Here's a link to my page: `http://mikeandersonart.com/level-design/the-order/`  To visualize the result, I'm using an embedded style to provide a yellow outline around elements that have the "view" class applied to them.  The elements with the full outline have the class applied to the `img` tag (done through the jquery script), while the image at the very bottom has it manually applied to its `<a>` tag, resulting in a half outline.  The half outline tells me it is working with my lightbox, as demonstrated if you click on it.

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly... I see this in your output: `<a href="http://mikeandersonart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ld_theorder_001.jpg" title="" class="view"><img width="300" height="168" src="http://mikeandersonart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ld_theorder_001-300x168.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></a>` and as you can see the `<a>` has the class, and in your whole gallery I see all of them with the yellow box... What browser are you on?

Comment: You're right, I checked in firefox as opposed to Chrome and the images do have the class applied to them. It seems I've got some additional work to figure out to make them behave as desired.  How are you seeing that output btw?  When I look at the page source I don't see the classes applied from the javascript.

Comment: Technically, the `<a>` has the class applied to it. Regarding the additional work it will depend on what lightbox you are using it might need another attribute. I'm seeing that output in the Chrome Developer tools in the latest stable version of chrome. So visually what I'm seeing is all your gallery items with a yellow box around them (this of course means the `.view` class is applied to them.)

Comment: I also figured that the reason you can't see the class added is because you are probably viewing the source normally as the documented was output, but the element manipulation (adding the class) is happening after the document is ready, so these kind of things are best seen with a developer tool that shows you what is happening in the live state of the website as per how the DOM is at that moment.

Comment: Thanks so, so much for your help, I learned A LOT from your suggestions.  Using the google dev tools, I see my links are getting the formatting I desired, even after I added `rel` attributes.  However, my lightbox is not responding, so it seems the trouble is on its end.